# Unable to access JENKINS web pages after setting the HOME environment variable

Tags: windows, git, ssh, jenkins

I am struggling to get Jenkins to work with SSH and after looking at a number of questions and answers the answer seems to involve setting the Windows Environment variable HOME.

When I set this environment variable and restart JENKINS, Jenkins starts properly but i can't access it via the URL:

> `http://localhost:8080`

Once I get rid of this variable and restart Jenkins it works well.

I am not sure why this variable is wreaking havoc? I am not sure how others have managed to set this variable and get things to work.

The outcome is the same, when i remove the Windows environment variable and replace it with the system property inside Jenkins.

Appreciate any suggestions/advice.

Thanks